# How to set the default user for authenticating a pamac command on Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, sudo, authentication, elevation

I recently added another user to my Linux installation, which I myself also use.

When I try to execute the `pamac` command, It has always asked for authentication with this header:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.manjaro.pamac.commit ====
```

Before I added the new user, it didn't ask me for a specific user, but now it always aks which identity I would like to use.

Is there a way I can set that to a default, or remove one of those from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the [*polkit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) elevation prompt, and pamac is using it in "auth_admin" mode – instead of asking for the caller's password (like sudo), it lists all users which are configured as "admins".

By default, all members of the `wheel` group are considered admin users in polkit. If you remove one of them, it should no longer show up in the list:

```
gpasswd -d BadUser wheel
```

If you remove all users, then auth_admin mode will ask for root password instead, if you prefer that.

(It's possible that your distro might have added custom rules which give admin rights to some other group – check for files in /etc/polkit-1/rules.d and /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d to make sure.)